# Python. Работа с многоуровневой структурой вложенностей в list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Есть такая странная структура данных:

```
[  
  [  
    {  
      'id':2,
      'name':'user_create',
      'entry_point':'UserCreation_endpoint'
    },
    {  
      'id':1,
      'context_id':2,
      'business_object_attribute_id':79,
      'required':True
    },
    {  
      'id':79,
      'name':'user login  ',
      'description':'2019-01-15T15:04:09.829763',
      'business_object_id':56,
      'is_mandatory':False,
      'column_name':'login',
      'catalog_data_type_id':2
    }
  ],
  [  
    {  
      'id':2,
      'name':'user_create',
      'entry_point':'UserCreation_endpoint'
    },
    {  
      'id':2,
      'context_id':2,
      'business_object_attribute_id':80,
      'required':True
    },
    {  
      'id':80,
      'name':'user password  ',
      'description':'2019-01-15T15:04:09.829926',
      'business_object_id':56,
      'is_mandatory':False,
      'column_name':'password',
      'catalog_data_type_id':2
    }
  ],
  [  
    {  
      'id':2,
      'name':'user_create',
      'entry_point':'UserCreation_endpoint'
    },
    {  
      'id':5,
      'context_id':2,
      'business_object_attribute_id':83,
      'required':False
    },
    {  
      'id':83,
      'name':'user personnel_number  ',
      'description':'2019-01-15T15:04:09.830517',
      'business_object_id':56,
      'is_mandatory':False,
      'column_name':'personnel_number',
      'catalog_data_type_id':2
    }
  ],
  [  
    {  
      'id':2,
      'name':'user_create',
      'entry_point':'UserCreation_endpoint'
    },
    {  
      'id':4,
      'context_id':2,
      'business_object_attribute_id':82,
      'required':False
    },
    {  
      'id':82,
      'name':'user email  ',
      'description':'2019-01-15T15:04:09.830354',
      'business_object_id':56,
      'is_mandatory':False,
      'column_name':'email',
      'catalog_data_type_id':2
    }
  ],
  [  
    {  
      'id':2,
      'name':'user_create',
      'entry_point':'UserCreation_endpoint'
    },
    {  
      'id':3,
      'context_id':2,
      'business_object_attribute_id':81,
      'required':False
    },
    {  
      'id':81,
      'name':'user phone  ',
      'description':'2019-01-15T15:04:09.830089',
      'business_object_id':56,
      'is_mandatory':False,
      'column_name':'phone',
      'catalog_data_type_id':2
    }
  ]
]
```

Мне необходимо превратить ее в dict c такими ключами:

```
{
    "login": value,
    "password": value,
    "personnel_number": value,
    "email": value,
    "phone": value
}
```

По логике, мне нужно брать каждый 3 dict в листе и записывать его в новый словарь, но как это сделать ума не приложу.
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = [  # Исходные данные
  [  
    {  
      'id':2,
      'name':'user_create',
      'entry_point':'UserCreation_endpoint'
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
]

v = {j['column_name']: j['name'] for i in d for j in i if 'column_name' in j}
```